El término 'pyinstaller' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable
No se como solucionar esto.. he estado leyendo toda la mañana y no veo la solucion;
Instale python 3.12 y vsc.
Añadi el path a las variables del entorno, tanto del sistema como del usuario (la carpeta de python 3.12 y la de scripts)
si ejecuto el comando "pip install pyinstaller" me dice: "Requirement already satisfied", cuando intento el update lo mismo. Osea, si esta instalado y actualizado pyinstaller, pero al ejecutar el comando para crear un .exe me dice lo siguiente:
pyinstaller : El término 'pyinstaller' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa
ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta
es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
como lo puedo solucionar??? estoy ejecutando pyinstaller en la carpeta donde tengo el .py

Tienes que instalar el ejecutable.
Desde la línea de comandos, escribe
pip install pyinstaller
